# jQuery: Appending an element to dynamically generated elements

Tags: jquery

**I have the following dynamically generated HTML - I see this html code in firebug but not when I right click and view page source**

```
     <table id="list2" class="ui-jqgrid-btable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" tabindex="1" role="grid" aria-multiselectable="true" aria-labelledby="gbox_list2" style="width: 1405px;">

<tr id="1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" role="row" tabindex="-1">
<td aria-describedby="list2_action" title="" style="text-align:center;" role="gridcell">
    <img height="22" width="22" alt="Edit" title="Edit" style="vertical-align:middle" src="images/action_icon.gif">
        </td>
</tr>
<tr id="2" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" role="row" tabindex="-1">
<td aria-describedby="list2_action" title="" style="text-align:center;" role="gridcell">
    <img height="22" width="22" alt="Edit" title="Edit" style="vertical-align:middle" src="images/action_icon.gif">
        </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Taking the above code, I want to dynamically add a div element after the img element such that every table row has the following code**

```
<td aria-describedby="list2_action" title="" style="text-align:center;" role="gridcell">
    <img height="22" width="22" alt="Edit" title="Edit" style="vertical-align:middle" src="images/action_icon.gif">
<div>test</div>
        </td>
```

I've tried `.append()`, `.add()`, `.insertAfter()` but nothing works.

Pls help! Is there a way to use `.live()` without an event handler?

**This is also not working and it's at the bottom right before the body end tag.**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img[alt='Edit']").after("<div style='background-color:yellow;'>test</div>");

});
```

Comment: How is the original HTML generated? Does your code already have some reference to those elements? What is going to trigger adding the extra div you want to add? And what does your last sentence about `.live()` have to do with the rest of the question? (And what would be the point of using `.live()` without an event handler?)

Comment: the original html is generated using jquery but I cannot touch that piece of code. I have to write fresh code to add the div element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you can't touch the original code that dynamically creates the markup, it seems like you would be best to "[monkey patch](http://webdevwonders.com/monkey-patching-extend-built-in-javascript-functions-with-custom-code/)" the original code to modify it so that after it runs as normal, it also calls your code to append the divs.

It's not ideal, but since you cannot use `.live()` to bind to when certain types of elements get created, it's probably your best bet.

See my jsFiddle for a working example using almost your exact markup: http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/9xmqE/

The crux of it is this Javascript:

```
// assume that this is the code you cannot touch that dynamically adds the rows:

function existingAddDynamicRows() {
    // ... omitted for brevity ...
}

// now, in our code, we want to "monkey patch" the old code's function so that we can call our own code after it

// first we store a ref to the existing function
var oldAddDynamicRows = existingAddDynamicRows;
// next, we redefine what the function does to also run our own code
existingAddDynamicRows = function() {
    oldAddDynamicRows(); // call the existing code to add the rows
    // now we can run our own code, like adding the <div>s in
    $('#list2 td img').after('<div>test</div>');
};

// now whenever that existing function gets run, it will also run our code as well
// e.g.
existingAddDynamicRows();
```

Let me know if you have any questions. The particular way you monkey-patch it might be different depending on how the existing code is structured.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after/):

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements.

Something like:

```
$('td img').after('<div>test</div>');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Lt6ku/

You may need to adjust the `td img` selector to match your HTML of course.

Comment: @SK11: What does the generated HTML really look like? Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/HJDwn/

Comment: @SK11: Works fine (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/BqkzZ/) with `#list2 td img` as the selector. Is that HTML in the DOM when you run your stuff?

Comment: It still doesn't work :( I get this html when I view it in Firebug.

Comment: ok, I updated again with more details. I also tried $("img[alt='Edit']").after("<div>test</div>"); in JSFiddle. It works there but somehow it's not working in my app code.

Comment: Are you sure that you're running your code *after* that HTML is in the DOM?

Comment: Make sure your code is running _after_ the code that generates all of the above. Is your code in a document ready handler, or...?

Comment: Yes, it's at the bottom just before the body end tag